# Defining variable with multiple values in parentheses uses 2nd value

Tags: javascript, variables, parentheses

Right so my question is:

```
var x = (val1,val2);
```

sets the value of x to val2;

Why?

Comment: [Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because that's how the [comma operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.14) works: It evalutes both its operands, and the result of the expression is the value of the second one.

Note that this is *very different* from what you'd have if you didn't have the parentheses there:

```
// Differs *significantly* from your example:
var x = val1, val2;
```

Without the parens, you wouldn't be using the comma operator at all, you'd be using the comma as part of the declaration list of the [`var` statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2), which has different semantics — specifically, that `x` gets the value of `val1` and you have a declaration for `val2`, which isn't initialized in that code.

But again, that's a different thing entirely.

Comment: OMG - you are totally right about the parens... Nice